# Request a web starting with a hyphen in python

Tags: python, url, ubuntu, urllib2, wget

### Python

I need to request some urls with python. I'm using standard urllib2 procdeure, for instance:

```
urllib2.urlopen('http://google.com')
```

Works with no problem. However when using a url that starts with a dash, for instance:

```
urllib2.urlopen('http://-cityoflove.tumblr.com/')
```

The script brokes with the error:

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>
```

Does anyone could thing on a way to get the domain from python?

### Ubuntu

If could be help full note that same error is happening with **wget**:

```
wget http://-cityoflove.tumblr.com/
```

That crashes with error:

```
wget: unable to resolve host address `-cityoflove.tumblr.com'
```

Note that this error is notified on ubuntu bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/resolvconf/+bug/668926

Comment: Hm. It works for me, tried python2.5, 2.6 and 2.7.

Comment: Fails for me on Debian with 2.7.3. `wget/ping` exhibit the same behavior. [Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname#Restrictions_on_valid_host_names) that this is not a valid hostname, which might be why.

Comment: What python version are you using? Operating system? Also, provide a full traceback please.

Comment: @alecxe python 2.7 over ubuntu 12.04

Comment: I strongly suggest using this library instead of urllib2: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Comment: @Lukas I agree with the recomendation but requests.get('http://-cityoflove.tumblr.com/') breaks also.

Comment: @DavidMabodo interesting, I cannot reproduce the problem on Mac OS X. Both `urllib2` and `curl` work.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the dash? `http://%2dcityoflove.tumblr.com/`

Comment: @choroba yes, however still the same problem.